# Excel: Formula to extract a string of text delimited by markers from cells

Tags: excel, vba, extract, formula

I'm messing with a spreadsheet containing postal addresses that have been inserted in the cells' comments
Each comment contain an address composed of a variable number of lines (damn UK addresses, they can have up to 7 lines!) in the following format:

```
Line1,
Line2,
Line3,
[...],
State
```

With my poor skills, I've managed to extract the comment with a VBA script, obtaining the following string on a single cell:

```
Line1,Line2,Line3,[...],State
```

At this point each string between commas must be extracted to its own cell.
I've managed to extract the 1st 3 lines with the following formulas:

For Line1:

```
=LEFT(A8;(SEARCH(",";A8))-1)
```

For Line2:

```
=MID(A8; SEARCH(",";A8)+1; SEARCH(","; A8; SEARCH(","; A8)+1)-SEARCH(",";A8)-1)
```

For Line3:

```
=MID(A8; SEARCH(",";A8;SEARCH(",";A8;SEARCH(",";A8;SEARCH(",";A8)))+1)+1;SEARCH(","; A8; SEARCH(","; A8;SEARCH(",";A8)+1)+1)-SEARCH(",";A8;SEARCH(",";A8)+1)-1)
```

From this point I start to get overflow errors from my brain... I probably need some days of sleep.

Can anybody help me to get to "line6", and finally suggest me how to pull out the "State line" which ends without comma?

I thought I could pull out the "State" line with =RIGHT(",";SEARCH(",";A8)-1) but I'm obviously doing something wrong because that pulls out a comma instead of a string.

I guess I could do everything with a VBA script, but I'm not that skilled yet :(

Comment: I'm aware of the Text to Columns function but it would be inconvenient.
Addresses are still being added to the spreadsheet and they need to be processed automatically.
In case someone wonders, the reason behind the addresses being added into the comments is to have some kind of formatting like you would have in a Word document, because every address is formatted differently according to the postal regulations of the addressee's country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to do this programmatically instead of using a built-in, check out the split function for chopping up your comma separated string. It will split up your input string into an array. Then you can do whatever you like with the array.

```
 Dim Names() As String

 Names() = Split(inputValue, ",")
 For i = 0 To UBound(Names)
    ' do what you want with each piece
 Next
```

Gary's Student's answer is great for using the built-in functions.

Answer (score 2):

With comma separated data in **A1,** in **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,",",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```

and copy across.  For example:

[image]

***Note:***

Why not use *TextToColumns* ?

- The row of formulas re-calculates automatically if **A1** changes.
- The row of formulas will work even if **A1**, itself, contains a formula.

Comment: Interesting method for achieving this. How did you ever come up with this?

Comment: Well, yes, he copy & pasted it from another answer he gave. I'd like to know where he got the idea from originally. It's an odd solution.

Comment: @KevenDenen..............I did not develop this formula........if I can retrieve the "source" I will update my Answer.

Comment: That is a fascinating formula for extracting data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a VBA solution:

```
Sub spitString()

    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim stringArr() As String
    Dim i As Integer


    Set sourceRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    stringArr = Split(sourceRange.Value, ",")

    For i = LBound(stringArr) To UBound(stringArr)
        sourceRange.Offset(0, i + 1).Value = stringArr(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid adding comments: Are you aware that users can add line breaks inside a cell by pressing ALT+RETURN?

If having high rows d is a problem and you don't like that  formatting,  an alternative approach might be to write a simple bit of code that changes the height of the current row when a user clicks in a certain range. It would , make other rows less high. Perhaps.

Just a thought.  It has benefits keeping it simple.

Harvey.